# Python, unpack and reorder list of ordered dictionaries

Tags: python, ordereddict

I have a list of ordered dictionaries.

I want to set the first value of every dictionary to be the key and the dictionary itself the value (including the name) and return a new list.

```py
data = [
    OrderedDict(
        [('Name', 'Tel saki'), ('Area', '210'), ('Latitude', 32.866477), ('Longitude', 35.830773), ('elevation', 481),
         ('date_added', '13-03-2020')]),
    OrderedDict(
        [('Name', 'Mitzphe shelagim'), ('Area', '210'), ('Latitude', 33.30445), ('Longitude', 35.797814),
         ('elevation', 2110), ('date_added', '29-03-2020')]), OrderedDict(
        [('Name', 'Mitzphe adi'), ('Area', '769'), ('Latitude', 33.2253981), ('Longitude', 35.5495681),
         ('elevation', 680),
         ('date_added', '17-03-2020')]),
    OrderedDict(
        [('Name', 'Nhahal Oz'), ('Area', '300'), ('Latitude', 31.4762228), ('Longitude', 34.4974832),
         ('elevation', 68),
         ('date_added', '30-03-2020')]),
    OrderedDict(
        [('Name', '105'), ('Area', '210'), ('Latitude', 33.220439), ('Longitude', 35.808097), ('elevation', 1127),
         ('date_added', '07-04-2020')]),
    OrderedDict(
        [('Name', 'Ifthah'), ('Area', '300'), ('Latitude', 31.5487777), ('Longitude', 34.4873539), ('elevation', 29),
         ('date_added', '08-04-2020')])]
```

My code:

```py
class RepackDictionaries:
    index = 0

    @classmethod
    def return_values_lists(cls):
        while cls.index < len(data):
            names = list(data[cls.index].values())[0]
            data_sets = [data[cls.index].values()]
            cls.index += 1
            return names, data_sets

    @classmethod
    def create_new_dicts(cls):
        names, data_sets = cls.return_values_lists()
        data = list(zip(names, data_sets))
        while cls.index < len(data):
            final_list = {name: data_set for name, data_set in data}
            cls.index += 1
            return final_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(RepackDictionaries.create_new_dicts())
```

Which outputs to None and I can't understand why.

Comment: That means for some reason the while loop isn't entered. You probably don't want to return from within th eloop in both functions, but from after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a class looks like overkill for such a trivial issue. A simple function using a dict comprehension would look like:

```
def repack(data):
    return {next(iter(d.values())): d for d in data}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset index value between function calls. You need to set `cls.index=0` after 
`names, data_sets = cls.return_values_lists()` in `def create_new_dicts(cls):`. Since you don't do that you never enter while loop in `def create_new_dicts(cls):`.

Why are you using index on a class level instead of within a function?